# iOS Change background image of navigation bar cancel button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIImagePickerController that pulls from the camera roll.

In the navigation bar, there is a default UIBarButtonItem to cancel selecting a photo, but it does not match my Application at all!

How can I change its appearance or even hide it and then put my own button in its place in the nav bar?

This is easily done with the Back button like so:

```
// Change the appearance of back button
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 10, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

There does not seem to be a setCancelButtonBackgroundImage method for UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
UIImage * cancelButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_button.png"];
UIButton * cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cancelButton setFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, hamburgerImage.size}];
[cancelButton setImage:cancelButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(cancel:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem * cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cancelButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelButtonItem];
```

Comment: I suppose that would work if I were to subclass UIImagePickerController. I would have to put it as the right bar button item (this is where the cancel button shows up on an ImagePickerController). Let me give it a shot and see if it works!